# Creating texture from getImageData (Javascript)

Tags: canvas, webgl, textures, texture-mapping, getimagedata

It is possibile to create a texture (to use on a element in a canvas) from the getImageData array of another canvas (in the same html page)? maybe without three.js? Thanks a lot,

Jennifer

Answer (score 2):

The coolest thing about WebGL's `texImage2D` method is that its last argument can be a DOM  element instead of an ArrayBuffer, in which case it copies its rendered content into your texture object.

For example:

```
var canvas2d = document.getElementById('canvas2d');
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, myTexture);
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, canvas2d);
```

There's a little tutorial about this feature [here](http://webglfactory.blogspot.com/2011/06/render-text-with-canvas-2d.html).

Comment: the tutorial is very interesting but the link at the source code is broken so I've not completely understood.. do you think that I can use texImage2d instead of getImageData or I should use a cocmbination of them?

Comment: I don't think you need to use `getImageData` at all, if you're simply trying to create a texture based on a "screenshot" of another canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Thats the point of getImageData, getting an image to manipulate it and then draw on any canvas.

```
imageData = someContext.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
anotherContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

doing things like: http://jsfiddle.net/jaibuu/myRGr/

If you don't intend to do pixel manipulation, you should only use drawImage(), without getImageData/putImageData which are slower though.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I don't want to draw the image into the second canvas, I want to use the pixel Array (a sort of Color Buffer if I have understood right) to create a texture for a cube (for example). In other words I want to "attach" the image to a 3d element as a texture for it. Thanks again

Comment: You need to create the a bitmap buffer/canvas in any case from the imageData anyway, then use the bitmap as your texture. ( or the canvas directly if you don't need pixel manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, texImage2D can take an ImageData.

```
var imageData = some2DCanvasContext.getImageData(...);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
```

Here are is one of the WebGL conformance tests that test this functionality

https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/textures/tex-image-and-sub-image-2d-with-image-data.html