# readPixels function returns not modified texture

Tags: javascript, webgl, framebuffer

I'm trying draw an image (as a texture) to a framebuffer, apply sharpness filter (by dragging slider on UI), then read result from the framebuffer and copy data to a simple 2d canvas (not webgl) by calling readPixels with the binded framebuffer, getting array with pixels and copying them to ImageData.data, but the function returns original texture.

Maybe someone can explain this to me, because as I understand, the thing on a screen is actually a framebuffer's content.

Sorry for a lot of code, but I hope it can help to understand what I'm doing.

```
(function () {
  var anotherContext = null;
  var canvas = $("#canvas");

  main();
  setupCanvas();

  function setupCanvas () {
    anotherContext = document.getElementById("anothercanvas").getContext("2d");
  }

  function main () {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "http://localhost:9292/img/ava.jpg";
    image.onload = function () {
      render(image);
    }
  }

  function render (image) {
    //-----get contexts----
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');

    //----define shaders-----
    var vs = document.getElementById('vshader').textContent;
    var fs = document.getElementById('fshader').textContent;

    //----create program-----
    var program = createProgram(vs, fs);
    gl.useProgram(program);

    //----setup vertex data-----
    var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
    var texCoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texCoord");

    //----setup texture-----
    var texCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
        0.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  0.0,
        0.0,  1.0,
        0.0,  1.0,
        1.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  1.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    // Create a texture.
    var texture = createAndSetupTexture();
    // Upload the image into the texture.
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

    //---framebuffer----
    var framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
    var canRead = (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) == gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);
    console.log("Can read: ", canRead);

    //----lookup uniforms and set the resolution-----
    var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");
    var textureSizeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_textureSize");
    var kernelLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_kernel[0]");

    gl.uniform2f(textureSizeLocation, image.width, image.height);

    //----kernels-----
    var kernel = [
       0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0
    ];

    var sharpnessKernel = [
       0,-1, 0,
      -1, 5, -1,
       0,-1, 0
    ];

    //-----bind buffer------
    var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vertexPosAttrib, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    setRectangle(gl, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

    draw(kernel);

    function draw (krn) {
      // gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

      setFramebuffer(framebuffer);
      drawWithKernel(krn);

      copyImage();

      // gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
      setFramebuffer(null);

      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    }

    function setFramebuffer (fbuf) {
      gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbuf);

      gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    function drawWithKernel (kernel) {
      gl.uniform1fv(kernelLocation, kernel);

      //---draw
      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    }

    function createAndSetupTexture () {
      var texture = gl.createTexture();
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

      // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

      return texture;
    }

    function setRectangle (gl, x, y, width, height) {
      var x1 = x;
      var x2 = x + width;
      var y1 = y;
      var y2 = y + height;
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
         x1, y1,
         x2, y1,
         x1, y2,
         x1, y2,
         x2, y1,
         x2, y2]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    function createShader(str, type) {
      var shader = gl.createShader(type);

      gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
      gl.compileShader(shader);

      return shader;
    }

    function createProgram (vstr, fstr) {
      var program = gl.createProgram();
      var vshader = createShader(vstr, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
      var fshader = createShader(fstr, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

      gl.attachShader(program, vshader);
      gl.attachShader(program, fshader);
      gl.linkProgram(program);

      return program;
    }

    function copyImage () {
      var pixels = new Uint8Array(image.width * image.height * 4);
      gl.readPixels(0, 0, image.width, image.height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

      var imageData = anotherContext.createImageData(image.width, image.height);
      for (var i = pixels.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        imageData.data[i] = pixels[i];
      };

      // console.log(imageData.data);
      anotherContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    }

    $("#slider").slider({
      min: 0,
      max: 99,
      slide: function (event, ui) {
        var currentKernel = null;

        //do not use any filtering if slider is on 0 position
        if(ui.value == 0) {
          currentKernel = kernel;
        }
        else {
          currentKernel = sharpnessKernel.slice(0);
          currentKernel[4] -= (ui.value / 100);
        }

        draw(currentKernel);
      }
    });
  }
})()
```

Comment: Just a quick suggestion (I'm about to head into the bed): Unbind the texture, before attaching it to the framebuffer object. There are certain rules regarding a texture binding and attachment status to a framebuffer, that inhibit operations on the framebuffer. The easiest part is to unbind the texture: `bindTexture(…, 0);` – however in your case a renderbuffer may be better suited as attachment, that a texture.

Comment: to datenwolf - This does not work either.

Answer (score -2):

Your current function and bracket setup is completely broken, which also suggests that you're not using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/errors) or any other [web-console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#basic_operation) to debug your javascript.

For a start you should move some functions outside of the main one and get a [modern editor](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) as most of them have means of showing brackets which belong together.

EDIT: Looks similar to the code from [WebGL fundamentals](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/webgl_fundamentals/). To answer your question: you're drawing to screen only if the bound framebuffer is null (as you can read on that site).

Anyway, you might be helped with this one: [Creating texture from getImageData (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372257/creating-texture-from-getimagedata-javascript) or possibly [fabric.js image filters](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters/)

Comment: Please, point places where it is broken. The code is a bit messy, but it is kind of proof of concept and it works. And btw, I'm using chrome dev. tools and sublime text editor - no problems with highlighting the brackets.

Comment: Downvoting answers won't help you, if you have those tools at your hand then use them! Keeping your code in order is half the programming and it should actually solve your problem, in your current code the browser is bailing out before executing any code because that code isn't valid.

Comment: Could you please tell me what exactly do you consider broken in the code? Otherwise your answer is not relevant at all and have nothing to do with reading framebuffer's content.

Comment: For once the closing brackets in your code are not matching the opening brackets, they need to be closed in the same order as they are opened. Also as said you should move functions out of the main one to improve readability for both the coder and the browser. As long as you're testing you can (and should) use global variables and functions, and even if you want to encapsule functionality then use [classes](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/). Throwing everything into a single function may work but it's bad practice and gets you into more problems the longer your code.

Comment: Look, it's not a production code at all. Thank you for telling me about best practices, but it does not matter because I just need to see that the prototype is working. Brackets are matched and code works fine, except it has the problem with a framebuffer. Please, if you do not have something to say about the actual problem, do not spam the question.