# Create a texture with data from a canvas three.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js

I am relatively new to Three.js and trying to create a texture from the data in another canvas.

To be more specific - I intend to use Heatmap.js to obtain a heat map. The heat-map is returned in another canvas. I would then like to use this heatmap as a texture on my scene.

Any ideas on how to go about doing this ?

I tried to create the texture out of that canvas but getting a black texture.

Comment: http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/ ?

Comment: Also, relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372257/creating-texture-from-getimagedata-javascript

Comment: Yes. I am using the same heat map. I did try the other method, but i still get a black texture

Comment: Some sort of alpha issue?  Can you get textures working from a non-heatmap canvas?

Comment: This is the warning I am getting -
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: width or height out of range three.js:25696
[.WebGLRenderingContext]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'

Comment: Besides heatmap-stuff, have you checked standard examples on how to get a texture from a canvas? I guess this is more of a problem then the heatmap-specifics. 
see here: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/
"Texture From Canvas"-Example

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with black textures. This may help:

```
// create texture from canvas
var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
// my solution:
texture.needsUpdate = true
```

Comment: Note that `THREE.CanvasTexture` is also available, and doesn't require the immediate `.needsUpdate=true` shown here.